# Replace fixed to variable potentiometer on DC regulator

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, dc, potentiometer, variable

I recently bought a DC regulator (power supply and tester.)
It is a 15V and 2A power supply with voltage fixed to 1.5V, 3.6V, 4.8V, 6.0V, 7.2V direct output of the sub-grade and the current is adjustable from 0.6 to 2A. It also has potentiometers for fine voltage and coarse voltage, but I do not get any difference when it is connected to a multimeter. I rotated the coarse and fine potentiometers but the output didn't change, not even when I connect it to other electronics.

Is it possible to change the potentiometer from fixed to variable?

[image: Fixed potentiometer]

[image: IC LM723CN]

[image]

Comment: This question would need much more detail to be answerable.  It kind of looks like maybe there's a selector switch somewhere which would select which one of those combinations would be active, and maybe that is not set for the one you were adjusting?

Comment: I believe you have to put you voltage selector knob to the last position.  Not sure waht you get now that you have tweaked calibration pots!

Comment: Where are you measuring to get no difference? They are three pin devices, make sure you're probing the correct pin.

Answer (score 3):

To the right of the current knob is a knob to select voltage.  It is set to 6V in your picture.  Rotate that knob so that it points to "3-15" or whatever the right most marking is.  That is the variable voltage setting.

With the selector knob set to the variable range, the coarse and fine voltage knobs will set the output voltage.